# Add custom String to URL in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a WordPress page with a dropdown location filter that shows the content of the page according to the selected location.

Without a selected location, the URL would look like this:
**domain.com/job-offers**

Now would like to display the selected location in the URL as follows, once the filter is selected:
**domain.com/berlin/job-offers**

The currently selected location is stored in a cookie.
How can I read the cookie and include the value of the cookie in the URL?

Answer (score -2):

write an action in it, either javascript or php:
1. add an event listener to the selecting changes, once the selected index changed, get the value of the location
2. post the value to the form, and form will go to the new URL with location in it.

Comment: What you need to alter is what you see in the navigation bar of the browser, it has nothing to do with submitting a form.

Comment: you make the selection(do the filtering), you get the changes, this is normally done by a form. the action is completed either by an ajax javascript in the front or by php at the backend. and then you give the router rule in the action accordingly, does it make sense?

Comment: Then the URL would be only displayed when submitting the form. I would like to display the location permanently in the URL as long as the filter is selected.